# JQuery problems with the ScrollTo() function

Tags: jquery

I have a menu like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#home_slider" id="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio_slider" id="portfolio">Potfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact_slider" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to use ScrollTo() to go to the parts when clicked. Im having trouble with the JQuery, so far I have:

```
$("#menu a").click(function(event) {
    $("#menu a").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.sliders').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'));      
     //cancel the link default behavior
     return false;        
});
```

I don't want the screen to move, I just want the .sliders div to horizontally scroll to the correct slider.

Check more code out here: http://www.rickdonohoe.co.uk.

Thanks for the help,

Rick

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions  may help.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo(x,y) means that the method is for scrolling to a point on the webpage referenced by an x and y coordinate value. You can't just pass it a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin. If so then the proper syntax is,

```
    $.scrollTo ($(this).attr('href'), 800);
```

Also, you need a click listeners for all those links,

```
   $('a[href$="_slider"]').click (function () {
      $.scrollTo ($(this).attr('href'), 800);
   });
```

Comment: I will explain myself a little better, I have this already:

    $("#menu a").click(function(event) {
        $("#menu a").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(".sliders").scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      
         //cancel the link default behavior
   return false;
    });

I want the horziontal slider to slide across within the .sliders div

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to set the value of the slider, although you don't include the 'slider' portion of your code, so we can't see how the slider relates to your navigation:

```
$(".sliders").slider('value', somevaluehere);
```

EDIT

I've just looked at your site and I can't see any sliders on the page at all.  My mistake.  I thought you must be using UI sliders.

Comment: <div class="sliders">
    <div class="panel" id="home_slider"></div>
    <div class="panel" id="portfolio_slider"></div>
    <div class="panel" id="contact_slider"></div>
    </div>